# "Far side of the Moon" in fewer words?

Tags: abbreviations

I'm looking for a shorter way of saying "The far side of the Moon" (meaning that either literally, or by association). Preferably in one word.

"Synthetic" English, Latin and other non-English (i.e. foreign language, not customarily used in English texts) words will do too (sadly, no linguistics.stackexchange.com out there).

Comment: To Floyd-ian boon, you seek to shorten the dark side of the moon, if a portmanteau will do, I suggest posterilune.

Comment: Note that "dark" and "far" side of the Moon is not the same. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_side_of_the_Moon#History

Comment: But `posterilune` is nice, why don't you add it as a proper answer?

Comment: I did see that. I was attempting humor.

Comment: I will consider adding it as an answer. I have to think of a better riff due to your good point above.

Comment: @Alexander: I see that you have an account on Area51. If you are interested in seeing the Linguistics StackExchange go live, please [commit to the proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6673/linguistics). Thanks.

Comment: @RegDwight: Done.

Comment: @RegDwight: But it seems that this question will be off-topic on linguistics SE as it defined in the proposal... :-)

Comment: @Alexander Gladysh: Isn't the far side the one which is hidden from the Sun?

Comment: @Alennano: In the New Moon the closest to Earth side of the Moon is the dark one.

Comment: **Distal** surface vs *proximal* surface would work. You'd probably have to be engaged in a fairly techy discussion to use it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested:

> Earlier I tried to be cute,
>   but ended looking a rube,
>   So for far-side of moon,
>   just say posterilune,
>   else more poems you'll see, awfully crude.

Comment: Of course, "posterior" and "moon" can be synonymous... ;)

Comment: @MT_Head - that is clbuttic!

Answer (score 6):

You could speak of the **translunar** surface, the way the we refer to Roman-era *transalpine* Gaul vs. *cisalpine* Gaul ("beyond the Alps Gaul" and "this side of the Alps Gaul").

Comment: Or (for another roughly alpine analogy) ultralunar like ultramontanist? Though I guess that is more beyond than behind...

Comment: *Translunar surface* has five syllables, just as many as *far side of the moon*.

Comment: @Peter Shor: The question says "fewer words" — not syllables. ^_^

Comment: *[Translunar](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/translunar)* already has established definitions incompatible with phrase "translunar surface"; to wit: "Situated beyond the moon or its orbit around the earth", "During transit from the Earth to the Moon", and "Outside the moon's orbit about the earth".

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was to construct a word similar to "[apogee](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/apogee)" or "[aphelion](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/aphelion)", so I thought "apolunar."  Unfortunately, this word [exists](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/apolune) (interestingly, an example of a Greek-Latin hybrid), and it doesn't mean that.  So I thought the all Greek version might work for you, but "[aposelene](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/aposelene)" also already has a meaning.

I share this because I thought it was interesting.  Given that my ideas were taken, I'm voting for `posterilune`.

Answer (score 0):

The middle of the far side of the Moon is the *antipodal point* to the Earth.

By analogy to other shiny round silver things often required for romantic evenings, i.e. coins, you could call the far side the *reverse* - and the near side the *obverse*.

Comment: Wouldn't work without appending "of the Moon". "Hey, have you seen *obverse* tonight?"